# Strange fortran pointers associations

Tags: pointers, fortran

It seems to me that, no matters how the following subroutine is call, it should never print true:

```
type :: node
class(node), pointer :: next => null()
end type node

...

subroutine add(nod)
class(node)               :: nod
type(node), pointer       :: new

allocate(new)
new%next=> nod%next
nod%next=> null()
new%next=> null()

nod%next=> new
print*, associated(new%next,target=new)
print*, associated(nod%next,target=new%next)
print*, associated(new%next)

end subroutine
```

However, using this subroutine in a larger code, I get true (in all the prints) at least one time.

This is not a minimal example, because when I construct one, I get false, of course. Actually in the full code I get false many times until I see the true. So I wondering, what happens in the full code to achieve this? In other words, how can I build a program that can call the `add` subroutine in such a way to make the output to be true. There could be another unrelated bug, another memory issue in other parts of the code, that can explain this behavior?

**EDIT**

I am not sure how, but this is related to an `allocate(a,source=b)` syntax where `a` and `b` are object like:

```
type :: atype
  type(node),pointer :: head
end type
```

After I changed `allocate(a,source=b)` to

```
allocate(a)
allocate(a%head)
```

The problem disappears.

Comment: As a first step you might have to turn on all compiler check and warning flags. Observe the memory usage of the program as it runs. Does memory increase steadily? Can you check the program with valgrind for memory leaks? Go through all lines of code and see if each alllocated object is deallocated in a pairwise fashion. Finally you might have to strip down the code subroutine by subroutine (place a comment at each call, temporarily replace needed results by dummies) until the error does no longer occur. Good luck!

Comment: This section of the code looks ok to me. Perhaps you have an error somewhere else (maybe a memory leak) that is causing unexpected issues. I agree with @Reinhard that you should try valgrind.